# Can't get margin: auto to stick with 960 grid system in IE7/8

Tags: css, 960.gs

I've read about quite a few people having a problem with this and I've tried all the solutions I can find - hopefully someone can't point out where I'm making a mistake.

I'm working on [this site](http://www.aboyandhismac.com/clients/TravelPlus/), and as far as I can tell, I'm in standards mode. The doctype is the first thing in the file, and it's valid. I've tried using a wrapper div or body tag with text-align: center and the container div using text-align: left.

I can't seem to find anything that works. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks like it's in the ie7.css file.  It has this rule:

```
* {
  display:inline;
  zoom:1;
}
```

Inline elements don't have margins.  You'll need to drop this rule, or add `display:block;` to `.container_12` somewhere.

Comment: I saw this 30 seconds after I posted this question. After 3 hours of tearing my hair out.